# Mocked service only being used when called from a function during Laravel unit test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm experiencing an issue where a mocked service is not being used during a Laravel unit test's `setUp` method, but weirdly, when I implement the very same code into a function and call that function, the mocking works. For context, I am trying to mock the `CustomerApi` service that's called from the User model's event listener:

```php
static::created(function (User $user)
{
    try {
        $customerApi = app(CustomerApi::class);
        $customerApi->register($user);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $user->forceDelete();
        throw $e;
    }
});
```

On my base TestCase, I have implemented a `createUser()` method to easily create users with the mocked service, and it has worked so far for many tests:

```php
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function createUser($attributes = []): User
    {
        $this->mock(CustomerApi::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('register')->once();
        });

        return User::factory()->create($attributes);
    }
}
```

In fact, when I call that function to create the user from my test's `setUp()` method the mocking goes as expected and the test passes:

```php
class DU2A_DailyUpdateInitializationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->createUser();
    }
}
```

However, when I copy the exact same code instead of calling the function, the service is not mocked and instead is executed normally:

```php
class DU2A_DailyUpdateInitializationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    
        $this->mock(CustomerApi::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('register')->once();
        });

        User::factory()->create();
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this happens, but I do need to reuse the code in this `setUp()`, since I'll modify it for different use cases in this test scenario. Why does this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Instead of `$this->mock` try `bind` or `instance` and let us know if it worked

Comment: The $this->mock should work as it call instance and i have multiple instances in my current project that has the same approach. I would guess you would call an creation of an user before you actually have mocked it. do you do other things in your setup methods?